# How to publish wear bundle and mobile bundle together as a multi-APK release using gradle-play-publisher?

Tags: android, google-developers-console, gradle-play-publisher

Using the [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) library, how can I upload both a wear bundle and a mobile bundle as a [Multiple-APK](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) release ?

Answer (score 0):

Wear app gradle

```
play {
    ...
    commit = false
}
```

Mobile app Gradle

```
play {
    ...
    commit = true
}
```

Then call:

```
./gradlew :wear:publishReleaseBundle :mobile:publishReleaseBundle
```